# Integrating GTM with Shopify

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, google-tag-manager

I have read from the documentation that GTM can be integrated on Shopify Plus stores. However, I have also read that from blogs that they can also integrate GTM on Shopify Standard stores.

So what is the difference between Plus and Standard in terms of GTM integration?

Another topic I want to know is how to use GTM to control the GA the hits from the Shopify GA Integration. Because I believe if I setup the GA Code in Shopify Settings and setup the GTM script, the GA code still fires hits to GA and GTM will just handle any other dataLayer and events. I cannot control the enhanced ecommerce and pageview hits with GTM.

**Edited**:
I just got in touch with Shopify Support, and the reason why they say that GTM is only available on Plus stores, is because Plus stores have access to the checkout.liquid which is required to integrate GTM on the checkout page for the whole site to work with GTM. Standard stores will not have GTM on checkout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTM integration is the same in Plus stores as in Standar stores. Paste your code in the beginning of the head and the begging of the body.

If you add GTM in the code, I would suggest removing the GA code in the Shopify preferences and adding it to your GTM to have full control of all triggers and events.

Comment: If I remove the GA code, does that mean I have to manually setup all the dataLayer push to GTM?

Comment: Yes if you want to have total control, it's the only way.